# Setting 2 alarms on one BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have an app that sends 5 different types of alarms at different times. Do I need 5 broadcast receivers as well? Is there a way to use one receiver?

```
Intent intenter = new Intent(getContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
intenter.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), int, intenter, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
```

Comment: One Receiver is sufficient. You can differentiate alarms with actions and/or extras on the `Intent`s.

Comment: U mean different number of pending intent?

Comment: /*different number for every notification*/ in place of int?